# What is difference general function and ramda function?

Tags: javascript, angular, methods

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.css']
})
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {
  data = [{
    key: "Reyes",
    val: 467
  }, {
    key: "Chu",
    val: 335
  }, {
    key: "Williams",
    val: 198
  }];

  customizeLegend2(point){
    console.log(this.data[0]);
  }

  customizeLegend = (point) => {
    console.log(this.data[0]);
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(){}
}
```

In Angular project,

I call a method from the HTML code,
When calling 'customizeLegend2', an error occurs saying that 'data' is undefined,
but calling 'customizeLegend' will work.

I think this is the difference in the call time before and after data is defined, but I am wondering why this phenomenon occurs fundamentally. Help!

+

```
<dx-pie-chart id="pie" [palette]="palette" [dataSource]="data" [startAngle]="90">
    <dxo-legend [customizeText]="customizeLegend">
    </dxo-legend>
    <dxi-series argumentField="key" valueField="val">
    </dxi-series>
    <dxo-size [width]="400"></dxo-size>
</dx-pie-chart>
```

(Additional information) I was drawing a pie chart using DevExtreme, and this is a problem that was found while binding a property called [customizeText] among them.

Comment: This "phenomenon" doesn't occur and what does this mean -> `difference in the call time before and after data is defined` 
Both of these work here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5vktp3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts 
So we are going to need a little bit more information to see what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), the function is automatically bound to the lexical context. This is not the case in methods or old-style functions.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience, the normal function will look for the "data" variable in the scope of the function and the "ramda function" (arrow function to be precisely) will have its father's scope. Therefore this.data will have the value of its father and run ok.

Answer (score 0):

In https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxPieChart/Configuration/legend/#customizeText

According to the document, while drawing the pie-chart, the internal this of the method called by the'customize' property in HTML was directed to the pie-chart element.